# How does a icmp packet (ping command) work in wireless network?

Tags: wifi, icmp

I have a question about PING :
In wired network, a ping packet go through wires, switch to get to the target. But in wireless network, how does it work?! I think that the ping packet will go to the wireless router and it forward the packet to the target host, is that right?! And if replace the wireless router by the access point, what will happen?
(sorry for my poor English >.<)

Answer (score 0):

PING is an ICMP message, so it will be delivered at this level. Whatever lower-level infrastructure or protocol is used, doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

From ping's point of view, a wireless network looks the same as an Ethernet cable. It's Ethernet either way, so ping doesn't care or know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the Wikipedia article on the [Internet protocol suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite), AKA TCP/IP.

The difference between wired networks and wireless networks is in the Link Layer and in the Physical Layer (which is usually ignored). On most wired networks you see see today, the Link Layer is named Ethernet, and in most wireless networks the Link Layer is 802.11a/b/g/n.

ICMP messages, including ICMP Echo request and ICMP Echo response, are on the Internet layer (conceptually; technically they're contained within IP packets), and are completely agnostic to the difference in the Link layer.

To directly answer your question about differences in link layers (assuming Ethernet and 802.11abgn):

- In a wired network employing hubs, the ICMP packet will be forwarded to all computers which will pick out the packet that is addressed to it (using the MAC address).
- In a wired network employing switches, the switch will map MAC address to port (using the ARP messages) and forward only the relevant packet to the port.
- In a wireless network in ad-hoc mode, the situation is similar to a wired network with hubs with clients acting as hubs... But a lot more complicated, because radio and wires have  have different characteristics as a shared medium
- In a wireless network in infrastructure mode, the situation is somewhat similar to a wired network with switches, where the access point plays the part of the switch. Don't be confused by consumer "broadband wireless routers" - they are compose of multiple parts, including a router (usually with 2 ports), an access point, and a switch (usually with 6 ports, 1 connected to the router, 1 connected the access point, and the other 4 are external ports).